# Trying to convert gregorian calendar to islamic calendar

Tags: java, hijri

I have used Hijri jar to convert the gregorian date to islamic date but if ramzan get delayed by a day or so how can i set the islamic date according to islamic date

Comment: what kind of error? Please post the stack trace

Comment: It means that your code does not work correctly. So, debug it. SO is not a "debug-my-code-for-me" service. You are welcome to ask questions that are not directly depend on you code logic.

Comment: [Check this link](https://code.google.com/p/hijricalendar/source/browse/trunk/HijriCalendar/src/HijriCalTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

use this script, it's very easy to edit 
 http://www.ar-php.org/ar-example-Date-php-arabic.html

Comment: i have solved it by using the hijri jar where it does all the function required only thing we have to add the jar and use the required function in the class